# Clear Part of overlay item in Google Maps in Android

Tags: android, maps

In my apps, I have few overlay items,
some are locations of schools,
others is a circle of 30metres around the current point.
As the current location changes from time to time, I want to clear the circle of overlay and redraw it again, however, the locations of schools are fixed, they do not need to change.
The question is, how can I clear part of overlay items?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to `clear Overlays`

`mapView.getOverlays().clear();`

and if you want to clear all in mapview

`mapView.removeAllViews();`

Then refresh your mapview